# Masking an url in rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url

```
www.abc.com/description.php?id=123035
```

when I write a url like

```
abc.com/123035/Four_Seasons_Hotel_Istanbul_at_Sultanahmet
```

I want to get the result. Rewrite won't see `"Four_Seasons_Hotel_Istanbul_at_Sultanahmet"` will see only id and will work.

How can that be done?

I have tried this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ description.php?id=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/[^/]+/?$ /abc/description.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: didnt work. The requested URL /abc/abc/description.php was not found on this server.